# Is the Confluent Platform based on Kafka free? open source?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Kafka itself is completely free and open source.

Confluent is the for profit company by the creators of Kafka. The Confluent Platform is Kafka plus various extras such as the schema registry and database connectors. I presume Confluent makes money by selling support contracts and services.

Is the Confluent Platform free and/or open source? Am I obligated to purchase licensing or paid support?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Confluent Platform is free and open source (see https://github.com/confluentinc/ for the source).

There is also a Confluent Platform Enterprise version that includes the Control Center monitoring app (which is not open source) and includes support for the core Kafka, Confluent Platform OS components, and Control Center.

See http://www.confluent.io/product for more details.

**UPDATE for Version 5.1 and above**

On Dec 14th, 2018 Confluent announced that that new versions of the Confluent Platform (starting with Version 5.1) will be distributed under a new Confluent Community License.

The detailed FAQ about the new license located at 
https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq includes the following question and answer:

“Is Confluent Community License open source?

Strictly speaking it is “source-available.” Many people use the phrase “open source” in a loose sense to mean that you can freely download, modify, and redistribute the code, and those things are all true of the code under the Confluent Community License. However, in the strictest sense “open source” means a license approved by the Open Source Initiative (“OSI”) which meets a particular set of criteria. The Confluent Community License is not approved by the OSI and likely would not be as it excludes the use case of creating a SaaS offering of the code. Because of this, we will not refer to the Confluent Community License or any code released under it as open source.”

Announcement of License changes:
https://www.confluent.io/blog/license-changes-confluent-platform

The actual Confluent Community License
https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license

Comment: so can I use enterprise bundle 5.5.1 without providing the license(anonymous as id) in the production ? we are using only kafka, schema-registry, zookeeper ...

Comment: Yes you can use Apache Kafka, Schema Registry, and Zookeeper from any bundle including the enterprise download without a license key. You just will not be able to open any trouble tickets with Confluent Support.

Comment: kafka connectors as well, is it ?

Comment: There are over 100 connectors now (with various licensing models)so as of Confluent Platform V6.0 the connectors are downloaded separately from the Confluent Hub and they are clearly tagged as open source, community licensed, and proprietary.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from their website's [product page](http://www.confluent.io/product).

> The Confluent Platform is an open source platform that contains all the components you need to create a scalable data platform built around Apache Kafka. These components draw on our experience building some of the largest streaming data pipelines in the world.

Here's the [download link](https://www.confluent.io/download/) for their product. <strike>It seems like they only make money off supporting their product if you choose to pay for it.</strike> They now offer a managed cloud service as well as support for their open source products.

Comment: The link is broken